# Getting a second bit of the internal representation of the number

Tags: c

Please, explain why by doing as follows I'll get a second bit of the number stored in `i` in it's internal representation.

```
(i & 2) / 2;
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: This would help [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Comment: Less obscure way of doing the very same = `if( (i & 2) != 0 )`

Comment: This question looks like a class exercise :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Doing `i & 2` masks out all but the second bit in `i`. <sup>[1]</sup>
2. That means the expression evaluates to either `0` or `2` (binary `00` and `10` respectively).
3. Dividing that by `2` gives either `0` or `1` which is effectively the value of the second bit in `i`.

---

For example, if `i = 7` i.e. `0111` in binary:

1. `i & 2` gives `0010`.
2. `0010` is `2` in decimal.
3. `2/2` gives `1` i.e. `0001`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> `&` is the bitwise AND in C. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) for an explanation on how bitwise AND works.

Comment: Perhaps your first sentence is a bit convoluted - I would state it as it masks to the the bits of `2` namely to `0000 0010` or something of this sort

Comment: @DanZimm Hmm maybe, edited it now, should be clearer.

Comment: Ya, I agree, unsure what the issue is with the downvoter, thought it was fine then as well as now.

Answer (score 3):

`i & 2`  masks out all but the second bit.

Dividing it by 2 is the same as shifting down 1 bit.

e.g.

```
i = 01100010
(i & 2) == (i & 00000010) = 00000010
(i & 2) / 2 == (i & 2) >> 1 = 00000001
```

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator is bitwise AND: for each bit, the result is 1 only if the corresponding bits of both arguments are 1.  Since the only 1 bit in the number 2 is the second-lowest bit, a bitwise AND with 2 will force all the other bits to 0.  The result of `(i & 2)` is either 2 if the second bit in `i` is set, or 0 otherwise.

Dividing by 2 just changes the result to 1 instead of 2 when the second bit of `i` is set.  It isn't necessary if you're just concerned with whether the result is zero or nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

`2` is `10` in binary. `&` is a bitwise [conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction). So, `i & 2` gets you the second-from-the-end bit of `i`. And dividing by 2 is the same as bit-shifting by 1 to the right, which gets the value of the last bit.

Actually, shifting to the right would be better here, as it clearly states your intent. So, this code would be normally written like this: `(i & 0x02) >> 1`